# hide element in another parent

Tags: html, css

How would i go about hiding or showing an element that is contained in a container, based on another container's hover state?

Here's what i have so far, as an example:

**HTML5**

```
<div class="left-menu-container">
    <div class="left-menu-inner-container">
        <div class="left-menu-item-container">
            <a href="AppsDashboard" class="left-menu-link">
                <div class="left-menu-item-first">
                    Find an Application
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="sub-menu">
                <input type="text" value="Enter app name here" onclick="Clear(this, 'Enter app name here');" onblur="Reset(this, 'Enter app name here');" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS3**

```
div.left-menu-container {
    float: left;
    width: 19%;
    padding-right: 1%;
}

div.left-menu-inner-container {
    width: 100%;
}
div.left-menu-item-container
{
    width:100%;
}

div.left-menu-item-first {
    width: 93%;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    transition: 0.15s ease-in-out;
    color: black;
    min-height: 26px;
    padding-left: 1%;
}

    div.left-menu-item-first:hover {
        width: 97%;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        color: white;
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(44,119,208),rgb(27,90,159));
        padding-left: 3%;
    }

div.left-menu-item-container .sub-menu {
    width: 97%;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    color: white;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(44,119,208),rgb(27,90,159));
    padding-left: 3%;
    display: none;

}

div.left-menu-item-first:hover left-menu-item-container.sub-menu {
    position:absolute;
    width: 80%;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    color: white;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(44,119,208),rgb(27,90,159));
    float:left;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1000;
    float: left;
}
```

However, that simply does not work. Hovering over the `left-menu-item-first` div does not show the `submenu` contained in the `left-menu-item-container` parent. Do they really and absolutely must be children of the parent for this to work with Pure CSS? I can and already had a JQuery version setup and going but i wanted to do it via CSS only if possible.

Comment: There is no parent selector in Css.

Comment: @SpencerMay that does not help op though, altering another element using css alone is only possible for child and sibling elements. never a different independent one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only alter child elements and sibling elements on hover, never a completely different element.

if you put the submenu right after the first menu element, you can use the sibling selector `+` as follows:

```css
div.left-menu-container {
    float: left;
    width: 19%;
    padding-right: 1%;
}

div.left-menu-inner-container {
    width: 100%;
}
div.left-menu-item-container
{
    width:100%;
}

div.left-menu-item-first {
    width: 93%;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    transition: 0.15s ease-in-out;
    color: black;
    min-height: 26px;
    padding-left: 1%;
}

    div.left-menu-item-first:hover {
        width: 97%;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        color: white;
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(44,119,208),rgb(27,90,159));
        padding-left: 3%;
    }

div.left-menu-item-container .sub-menu {
    width: 97%;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    color: white;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(44,119,208),rgb(27,90,159));
    padding-left: 3%;
    display: none;

}

.left-menu-link:hover + .sub-menu {
    position:absolute;
    width: 80%;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    color: white;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(44,119,208),rgb(27,90,159));
    float:left;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1000;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-menu-container">
    <div class="left-menu-inner-container">
        <div class="left-menu-item-container">
          <span class="AppsDashboard">
            <a href="AppsDashboard1" class="left-menu-link">
                <div class="left-menu-item-first">
                    Find an Application
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="sub-menu">
                <input type="text" value="Enter app name here" onclick="Clear(this, 'Enter app name here');" onblur="Reset(this, 'Enter app name here');" />
            </div>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that would be great. But the problem i have and don't want to have is that the link should only cover the first div, not the submenu, which means that they are no longer siblings, correct?

Comment: @MaxOvrdrv correct, but you can work around that as well. simply attach the hover to the link

Comment: @MaxOvrdrv i have updated the answer, see if its more convenient to implement

Comment: thank you... changing the hovering CSS to use the link as well as the div, and then using the sibling clause, it works!

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no CSS parent selector, try altering your html such that the hovered item is a sibling of left-menu-item-container.sub-menu
Try using a [CSS sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors):

Change:

```
div.left-menu-item-first:hover left-menu-item-container.sub-menu
```

to

```
div.left-menu-item-first:hover + left-menu-item-container.sub-menu
```

Or

Change:

```
div.left-menu-item-first:hover left-menu-item-container.sub-menu
```

to

```
.left-menu-link:hover + left-menu-item-container.sub-menu
```

Comment: You are right MaxOvrdv - You will need to make the hovered element a sibling.